# do constant calculations in #define consume resources?

Tags: c++, c, constants, preprocessor, calculation

as far as I'm concerned, constants and definitions in c/c++ do not consume memory and other resources, but that is a different story when we use definitions as macros and put some calculations inside it. take a look at the code:

```
#include "math.h"
#define a 12.2
#define b 5.8
#define c a*b
#define d sqrt(c)
```

When we use the variable 'd' in our code, does it spend time for CPU to calculate the SQRT and add operations or this values are calculated in compiler and just replaced in the code?
If it is calculated by CPU, is there anyway to be calculated beforehand in preprocessor and assigned as a constant here?

Comment: `#define` does not calculate anything!

Comment: `#define`, and all other preprocessor directives, are just text manipulation. Writing `d` or `sqrt(12.2*5.8)` are  exactly the same regarding to resources consumption at running time. The compiler itself, when running after preprocessing, may optimize some code. For example it will probably compute `12.2*5.8` and replace it with `70.76` in generated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> as far as I'm concerned, constants and definitions in c/c++ do not consume memory and other resources,

It depends on what you mean by that.  Constants appearing in expressions that potentially are evaluated at runtime have to be represented in the program somehow.  Under most circumstances, that will take some space.

Even (in C++) a `constexpr` *can* be evaluated at runtime, even though implementations can and probably do evaluate them at compile time.

> but that is a different story when we use definitions as macros and put some calculations inside it.

Yes, it is different, because macros are not constants in any applicable sense of that term.

> take a look at the code:
>
> ```
> #include "math.h"
> #define a 12.2
> #define b 5.8
> #define c a*b
> #define d sqrt(c)
> ```
>
> When we use the variable 'd' in our code,

`d` is not a variable.  It is a macro.  Wherever it appears within the scope of those macro definitions, it is exactly equivalent to the expression `sqrt(12.2*5.8)` appearing at that point.

> does it spend time for CPU
> to calculate the SQRT and add operations or this values are calculated
> in compiler and just replaced in the code?

Either could happen.  It depends on your compiler, probably on compilation options, and possibly on other code in the translation unit.  Pre-computation is more likely at higher optimization levels.

> If it is calculated by CPU,
> is there anyway to be calculated beforehand in preprocessor and
> assigned as a constant here?

Such a calculation is not part of the semantics of the preprocessor *per se*.  To the somewhat artificial extent that we draw a distinction between preprocessor and compiler in modern C and C++ implementations, if a precomputation is performed then it will be performed by the compiler, not the preprocessor.

The C and C++ languages do not define a mechanism to force such evaluations to be performed at compile time, but you can make it more likely by increasing the compiler's optimization level.  Or in C++, there is probably a way to use a template to wrap the expression in a `constexpr` function computing its value, which would make it very likely to be computed at compile time.

But if a constant is what you want, then you always have the option of pre-computing it manually, and defining the macro to expand to an actual constant.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard doesn't specify whether the calculations required when using `d` (i.e. `sqrt(12.2 * 5.8)` is done at compile time or at run time. It's left to the individual compiler to decide.

Example:

```
#define a 12.2
#define b 5.8
#define c a*b
#define d sqrt(c)

float foo() {
    return d;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%f\n", foo());
}
```

may result in (using https://godbolt.org/ and gcc 10.2 -O0)

```
foo:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movss   .LC0(%rip), %xmm0
        popq    %rbp
        ret
.LC1:
        .string "%f\n"
main:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movl    $0, %eax
        call    foo
        pxor    %xmm1, %xmm1
        cvtss2sd        %xmm0, %xmm1
        movq    %xmm1, %rax
        movq    %rax, %xmm0
        movl    $.LC1, %edi
        movl    $1, %eax
        call    printf
        movl    $0, %eax
        popq    %rbp
        ret
.LC0:
        .long   1090950945
```

and for -O2

```
foo:
        movss   .LC0(%rip), %xmm0
        ret
.LC2:
        .string "%f\n"
main:
        subq    $8, %rsp
        movl    $.LC2, %edi
        movl    $1, %eax
        movsd   .LC1(%rip), %xmm0
        call    printf
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        addq    $8, %rsp
        ret
.LC0:
        .long   1090950945
.LC1:
        .long   536870912
        .long   1075892964
```

so in this example we see a compile time calculation. In my experience all the major compilers will do that but it's not a requirement made by the C standard.

Comment: But if optimisation flags are used, will the compiler cache the result?

Comment: @kesarling Not sure what you mean... the C standard doesn't say anything about that

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. OP has used c as well as c++ tags. Aren't the standards different?

Comment: For sure C and C++ are different. AFAIK they don't differ on this point. However, in C++ const expressions are recommend instead of defines

Answer (score 0):

To understand this, you need to understand how `#define` works! `#define` is not a statement which the compiler even receives. It is a preprocessor directive, which means, it is processed by the preprocessor. `#define a b` literally replaces all occurrences of `a` with `b`. So, as many times as you call `sqrt(c)`, that many times, it will be replaced by `sqrt(a*b)`. Now, the standards do not mention whether something like this will be calculated at runtime or at compile time, and it has been left to the individual compiler to decide. Although, usage of optimisation flags will [definitely impact](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67799544/11930602) the end result. Not to mention, neither of those variables will be type safe!

Comment: The conclusion is not supported by the facts.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, Can you please clarify what do you mean by 'the conclusion'? :)

Comment: At least everything from "which means, equal number of times [...]" onward.

Comment: @kesarling: I am not sure I can speak for John here, but I think it would make this answer much much better if you can write a code with such macros, generate an assembly file and show comparison of the the same with the source that does not contain these macros, but the actual code. Also *"This means extra unnecessary CPU usage"* is not relatable and vague.

Comment: Although, I do wanna ask this, won't the replacement occur the way I have stated in the answer?

Comment: @WedaPashi, by *this means extra unnecessary CPU usage*, what I mean is that CPU will have to calculate the same code over and over again (unless OP uses optimisation, in which case CPU will probably cache the result)

Comment: @kesarling: AFAIK, yes the replacement would be done by preprocessor as you rightly said. However, ["which means, equal number of times a*b will be calculated! This means extra unnecessary CPU usage."] is slightly misleading/vague who doesn't understand this stuff, example: OP.

Comment: @kesarling, the semantics of the code are *as if* replacement occurs as you describe.  But that does not necessarily mean that the replacements are all actually performed.